# Spring - how do you refresh UI after external event?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Using Spring and Thymeleaf, I have a web page that must update displayed information based on external events. I have a thread running that catches the external events and updates the internal information. But how do I get the web page to update after that?

I've found one post that suggested an JavaScript timer to do the update...Is that the best way?

Cheers

Lori <*>

Comment: Your server is not going to be able to force the client browser to refresh.  You'll probably want some JavaScript in the client to check the server periodically and then force a page refresh when appropriate.

Comment: That is what I am finding. I've added a timer to my code that is very simple:

Answer (score 0):

Added the following JavaScript timer to my web page:

```
<script>
  function beginrefresh() {
    setInterval("refresh()", 5000)
  }
  function refresh() {
    method = "post";

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "refresh");
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);

    form.submit();
  }
  window.onload = beginrefresh;
</script>
```

Cheers

Lori <*>